# Python remove word containing "l"

Tags: python, file, input, output

I'm currently working on a small program.

The aim of the program is to take an input from a file, edit the file to remove any word containing the letter "l" and then output this into an output file.

The code I have at the moment works, however, it does not remove the word containing the letter "l" just the letter itself.

Here is my code

```
def my_main(ifile_name, ofile_name):
    ifile_name = open(ifile_name, 'r')
    ofile_name = open(ofile_name, "w+")
    delete_list = ['l']
    for line in ifile_name:
        for word in delete_list:
            line = line.replace(word, "")
        ofile_name.write(line)
    ifile_name.close()
    ofile_name.close()
```

Thank you

UPDATE

This is what the input file looks like:

```
The first line never changes. 
The second line was a bit much longer. 
The third line was short. 
The fourth line was nearly the longer line. 
The fifth was tiny. 
The sixth line is just one line more.
The seventh line was the last line of the original file.
```

And the output file should look like the following when the code is correct

```
The first never changes. 
The second was a bit much. 
The third was short. 
The fourth was the. 
The fifth was tiny. 
The sixth is just one more.
The seventh was the of the.
```

Comment: you need to split on spaces and then use regular expression to match the letter to the word and if its the case replace with an empty string

Comment: It doesn't work because you are replacing l with nothing. Meaning your delete_list becomes empty. You need to use replace with your ifile_name and not with delete_list. Thus your ifile_name writes empty.

Comment: How large is the file? Can it fit fully into the memory?

Comment: @RNar the words to be removed contain the letter `'L'` lower case `'l'` looks like capital `'i'`

Comment: Its word with the letter "l" as in the small version of "L". You might have mistaken it for the letter "i" perhaps? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

without seeing what your file is like its hard to tell what exactly to use so if you could update the question that would be great

but currently you are looping through each letter instead of the words... use split() to split the words into a list and change that list then rejoin the words together to have a string without the words that contain your letter

```
words = ''
with open(ifile_name,"r") as file:
    for line in file:
        list_of_words = line.split(' ')
        for key, word in enumerate(list_of_words):
            if 'l' in word:
                list_of_words[key] = ''

        words += ' '.join(w for w in list_of_words if w != '')
        words += '\n'

with open(ofile_name, "w+") as file:
    file.write(words)
```

the nice thing with this is you dont have any issues with white space. you will get a regular string with single spaces

EDIT: as pointed out in the comments a better way to do this (non in memory one for the whole file) is to do it inline

```
with open(ifile_name,"r") as in_file, open(ofile_name, "w+") as out_file:
    for line in file:
        list_of_words = line.split(' ')
        for key, word in enumerate(list_of_words):
            if 'l' in word:
                list_of_words[key] = ''

        out_file.write(' '.join(w for w in list_of_words if w != ''))
```

Comment: Hi John, I have updated the questions. Apologies for that.

Comment: Hi @colin! no worries, I updated my answer. it should be a working solution and its fairly simple to understand whats happening. but if you have any questions about it feel free to ask and I can explain :)

Comment: Thank you John, I really appreciate your help. Also, thanks for pointing out about the question , I am quite new to stack overflow and also to python. Its great to have people like you to get advice and helped when needed, especially outside class time. Thanks John.

Comment: @colin sure thing! if you have more questions you can ask me and I'll be happy to help :) if this answer solves your question dont forget to mark it as accepted with that check mark next to the votes! that way the question can be considered resolved :)

Comment: Hi John, sorry to be annoying but with the above code the output I receive when I open the output file is the following " The seventh was the line of the file. " . I hope you don't think I'm looking for you to solve my problem, more just to advise you. Thanks.

Comment: @colin yep I missed one small thing updating the answer to fix it for you.. try it now

Comment: @PadraicCunningham I want to create a new file. The program will read from the input file and make all changes to an output file.

Comment: Worth pointing out this potentially store a whole lot of data in memory and removing from a list is an `O(n)` operation, there is no real need at all to store the data in memory as you are writing the data to another file, more importantly this will also remove the wrong words from your list. You should never mutate a list you are iterating over

Comment: Your edit is still not going to work, when you delete from a list your are moving pointers, your code is going to remove the wrong words https://repl.it/B3hz

Comment: yes it is. i changed the logic to not mutate the list but change the value and check to make sure the value isn't an empty string.

Comment: Forget enumerate,      `out_file.write(' '.join([w for w in list_of_words if "i" not in w]) + "\n") `, a list is also more efficient to pass to join as you end up using a list regardless

Answer (score 1):

If you only want a complete new file without keeping a record of the words removed then it is a very simple solution that does not require you to store all the data in memory:

```
def remove_words(in_file, to_remove, out_file):
    with open(in_file) as f, open(out_file, "w") as f2:
        f2.writelines(" ".join([word for word in line.split()
                         if not to_remove.issubset(word)]) + "\n"
                             for line in f)


remove_words("test.txt", {"l"}, "removed.txt")
```

So now removed contains your updated lines:

```
In [23]: cat test.txt
The first line never changes.
The second line was a bit much longer.
The third line was short.
The fourth line was nearly the longer line.
The fifth was tiny.
The sixth line is just one line more.
The seventh line was the last line of the original file.

In [24]: remove_words("test.txt",{"l"},"removed.txt")

In [25]: cat removed.txt
The first never changes.
The second was a bit much
The third was short.
The fourth was the
The fifth was tiny.
The sixth is just one more.
The seventh was the of the
```

Comment: isn't `{` the literal notation for a dictionary? `{"1", "2"}` is invalid syntax no? I may be mistaken and i'm not trying to be rude or anything, just thought since you said set in the comment you wanted a set which is usually denoted with parenthesis.. you could specify `set('i', 'j')`. is that a new python 3 thing?

Comment: @JohnRuddell, nope, it depends how you use it `{K:V}` is a dict literal , `{a,b}` is a set literal

Comment: Oh ok, well then my bad sorry about that.. Learn a new thing every day :)

Answer (score 1):

An idea might be to use a [*regular expression*](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html) `re.sub(r'\S*l\S*',r'',text)`, the full program then reads:

```
import re

def my_main(ifile_name, ofile_name):
    with open (ifile_name,"r") as ifile_name :
        text=ifile_name.read()
    text2 = re.sub(r'\S*l\S*',r'',text)
    with open(ofile_name, "w+") as ofile_name :
        ofile_name.write(text2)
```

A problem is that only the word itself will be removed, not its surrounding spaces. A potential solution is to capture space next to (or before) the word as well:

```
re.sub(r'\S*l\S*\s*',r'',text)
```

The program the reads:

```
import re

def my_main(ifile_name, ofile_name):
    with open (ifile_name,"r") as ifile_name :
        text=ifile_name.read()
    text2 = re.sub(r'\S*l\S*\s*',r'',text)
    with open(ofile_name, "w+") as ofile_name :
        ofile_name.write(text2)
```

A potential downside of this approach is that the file needs to fit into (virtual) memory: for huge files (1 GiB+), the process will probably slow down or even get killed by the operating system for using too much resources.

Answer (score -1):

well think about it, what are you looping through?

```
for line in ifile_name: #line == every line in the file
    for word in delete_list: #word is equal to every 'word' (although it is mroe a letter) in delete_list
        line = line.replace(word, "") #you are replacing word (which is 'l') with a space
```

you probably want something more like:

```
for line in ifile_name:
        for word in line.split(): #iterate through words in your line, not delete_list
            if any(x in word for x in delete_list): #check if any of the letters in delete_list are in word
                line = line.replace(word,'') #replace the whole word with blanks
```

note that with this code, you will be left with extra spaces:

```
this_line_is -> this__is
    ^    ^          ^^
```

so you can call: `line = line.replace(word+' ', '')` but this may cause problems with cases like `'wordwithl.'`